# Mysql Query select where the sum from one table is compared to the sum of rows in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with each having amounts.

Table One:

```
id | name               | amount
1  | Dana Johnson       | 40
2  | Mary James         | 20
3  | Mark Lucas         | 10
```

Table Two:

```
id  | purchase_id  | amount  
1   |  max         |  25       
2   |  James       |  15       
2   |  Dane        |  10
```

So I want to select the first users on **table** **One** where their total sum is equal to the sum of the amount on **table two**.

I.e. if the sum of the 1st two users is equal to the total sum of the amount in table 2; so it should return the two users only leaving the last one behind.

I need the MySQL query for that for I don't know the syntax for that.

**Result** it **could** return

```
id | name               | amount
1  | Dana Johnson       | 40
2  | Mary James         | 20
```

Assuming the total amount on table 2 is 60, it selects the row 1 and row 2 since their sum is equal to 60.

Comment: Give an example.

Comment: @AshrafulIslam I don't have the code concept so that is why i'm asking

Comment: I mean what will be the output from your sample data ? and why ?

Comment: The sum of the amount values in your table two is only 50, how do you get those outputs?

Comment: i said assuming @xcvd

Comment: Yup, I got it the first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table1
where id <= (
    select a.id
    from table1 a
    join table1 a1 on a1.id <= a.id
    group by a.id
    having sum(a1.amount) >= (select sum(amount) from table2)
    order by a.id
    limit 1
)
```

The subquery will return the id of the first row which meets the condition that  the sum of amounts of all previous rows (including itself) is greater or equal to `sum(amount)` from `table2`. The outer query will select only rows until this one.

Demo: http://rextester.com/IQDNW80383

Comment: Downvoter: Please add a comment, so I can improve my answer. I also added a workig demo.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @id int
declare @name nvarchar(200)
declare @amount decimal(18,2)
delcare @amounttocompare decimal(18,2)
set @amounttocompare =0
declare @totalamount decimal(18,2)
select @totalamount =sum(amount) from tabletwo

create table #tempTable
(
    id int,
    name nvarchar(200),
    amount decimal(18,2)
)

DECLARE mycursor CURSOR FOR Select id, name, amount FROM tableone

OPEN mycursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor   INTO @id, @name, @amount

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  if @amounttocompare>@totalamount 
  begin
    break
  end
  @amounttocompare= @amounttocompare +@amount
  inset into #tempTable values(@id,@name,@amount)
 FETCH NEXT FROM mycursor INTO @id, @name, @amount
END

CLOSE mycursor 
 DEALLOCATE mycursor 

 select * from #temptable
```

This may have some errors but this is what I could come up while having morning coffee.

Answer (score -1):

`$first = SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table2`

`$second = SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE amount >= $first`

Comment: that is not what i want i want to compare the sum of the first to the sum of the second table.

Comment: im actually confused on what you want. You just want to compare the first 2 users sum? or for every 2 users sum?

Comment: Assuming the total amount on table A is 20, i want use that 20 to select all the user(s) on table B that their amount sum up to 20, so if user a + user b amount sum up to 20, then i will select just user a and b. Not just the first two user but all users but i will stop when the amount equals to the total sum of table A

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.